# Is a planet hot inside because it is still hot from beginning, or continuously heated?

Tags: thermodynamics, newtonian-gravity, planets, radioactivity, tidal-effect

If a planet emerges from multiple colliding pieces, that causes its material heat up.

Later, an existing planet is continuously heated by radioactive decay, tidal forces and other effects.

But are planets like the Earth hot because they are

- **still hot** from that time and did not cool, or
- **heated later** with only minor initial heat, or even
- **both** in significant fractions?

Comment: Neglecting surface heat, as your title says "inside" is dealt with here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_internal_heat_budget

Comment: Related recent question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/530369/123208

Comment: https://cseligman.com/text/planets/magnetism.htm